# built-in camera is not recognized, Microsoft Surface Go 3, Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: webcam

The 2 Webcams of my Surface Go 3 are not working and did not get detected.
I tried the `lsusb` command and got an output of

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:09b5 Microsoft Corp. Surface Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

no camera there. Also I tried to install libcamera and used the `cam -l` and `cam --list` command both with output `libcamera v0.0.0 Available cameras:` so also not recognized there. Cheese shows: *there was an error playing video from the webcam*.
The camera worked when Windows 11 was installed.
Is there anything that might fix this ? Thanks for taking time.

Comment: https://github-wiki-see.page/m/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Camera-Support

Comment: I followed the instructions there , led me to trying libcamera and that is not working